# Breadth First Traversal With Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

Maybe fast/simple Question. I have a a Binary Tree Implemented already, Then I was hoping to convert binary search tree into an array or at least print it out as if in an array. Where I am having trouble with is how to get the NULL/flags in there '\0'.

for example lets say I have a tree like:

```
                10
               /  \
              6   12
             / \   \
            1  8   15
             \
              4
```

And I want it to print how its supposed to print. Like:

```
        [10,6,12,1,8,\0,15,\0,4,\0,\0,\0,\0,\0,\0]
        ^Something Like this^ I don't know if I counted the NULL correctly.
```

Or Another Option on how i want to go about showing Visually my Tree is how to get the spacing correctly outputted like with the '/' and '\' pointing to the keys from the parents:

```
                10
               /  \
              6   12
             / \   \
            1  8   15
             \
              4
```

Here is something that I tried elaborating on code wise but im stuck:

```
void BreadthFirstTravseral(struct node* root)
{
    queue<node*> q;

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }
    for (q.push(root); !q.empty(); q.pop()) {
        const node * const temp_node = q.front();
        cout<<temp_node->data << " ";

        if (temp_node->left) {
            q.push(temp_node->left);
        }
        if (temp_node->right) {
            q.push(temp_node->right);
        }
    }
}
```

Any Kind of Help or Link and or advice and or example code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be very hard to get the spacing correctly as a key may have multiple digits and this should affect the spacing for all levels above the given node.

As for how to add `NULL` - simply add else clauses for your ifs where you print a NULL:

```
if (root) {
  q.push(root);
  cout << root->data << " ";  
} else {
  cout << "NULL ";
}
while (!q.empty()) {
    const node * const temp_node = q.front(); 
    q.pop();

    if (temp_node->left) {
      q.push(temp_node->left);
      cout << temp_node->left->data << " ";
    } else {
      cout << "NULL ";
    }


    if (temp_node->right) {
      q.push(temp_node->right);
      cout << temp_node->right->data << " ";
    } else {
      cout << "NULL ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the While loop go forever because nothing is ever being pop'ed off of the q? Infinite loop is what my computer system is implementing.

Comment: @Xaphen yeap thank you. I forgot to pop. Will fix that right away

Answer (score 3):

```
void TreeBreadthFirst(Node*  treeRoot) 
{  
 Queue *queue  = new Queue();

      if (treeRoot == NULL) return;
       queue->insert(treeRoot); 
       while (!queue->IsEmpty())
          {          
          Node * traverse = queue->dequeue();
         cout<< traverse->data << “ “ ;
          if (traverse->left != NULL) 
            queue->insert( traverse->left); 
          if (traverse->right != NULL) 
            queue->insert(traverse->right); 
           } 
      delete queue;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a program in c. This code will display somewhat like a tree.

```
struct node{
    int val;
    struct node *l,*r;
};

typedef struct node node;


int findDepth(node *t){
    if(!t) return 0;
    int l,r;
    l=findDepth(t->l);
    r=findDepth(t->r);

    return l>r?l+1:r+1;
}

void disp(node *t){
    if(!t)
        return;
    int l,r,i=0;
    node *a[100],*p;
    int front=0,rear=-1,d[100],dep,cur,h;
    a[++rear]=t;
    d[rear]=0;
    cur=-1;
    h=findDepth(t);
    printf("\nDepth : %d \n",h-1);

    while(rear>=front){
        dep = d[front];
        p=a[front++];
        if(dep>cur){
            cur=dep;
            printf("\n");
            for(i=0;i<h-cur;i++) printf("\t");
        }
        if(p){
            printf("%d\t\t",p->val);
            a[++rear]=p->l;
            d[rear]=dep+1;
            a[++rear]=p->r;
            d[rear]=dep+1;
        }
        else printf ("-\t\t");

    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation for the code and edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void BreadthFirstTravseral(struct node* root)
{
    queue<node*> q;

    if (!root) {
        return;
    }
    for (q.push(root); !q.empty(); q.pop()) {
        const node * const temp_node = q.front();
        if( temp_node->special_blank ){
            cout << "\\0 " ;
            continue;//don't keep pushing blanks
        }else{
            cout<<temp_node->data << " ";
        }
        if (temp_node->left) {
            q.push(temp_node->left);
        }else{
            //push special node blank
        }
        if (temp_node->right) {
            q.push(temp_node->right);
        }else{
            //push special node blank
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the "special_blank" identifier?

Comment: You can add a bool to the node structure.  It will be false if not special node, and true otherwise.  That way you catch the special blank node and print the empty leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
std::vector<node*> list;
list.push_back(root);
int i = 0;
while (i != list.size()) {
  if (list[i] != null) {
    node* n = list[i];
    list.push_back(n->left);
    list.push_back(n->right);
  } 
  i++;
}
```

Not tested but I think it should work.